# How to display SVG in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, svg, new-operator

I'm new to Eclipse and trying to display a SVG file in an Eclipse program. I have downloaded Batik plugin and installed it. This is my first time working with plugins so I don't know anything. I would like to display a SVG picture when I click on a button. Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried? What problem do you encounter?

Comment: I copied and altered couple of codes but nothings worked. Then i just copied some code i found (it was massive) and it had a lot of errors. I really need just an example code (which i can't find) of how to just display a svg file. No need of nothing more. I just want to press a button and a picture to appear afterwards. Consider that I'm pretty new to java.

Comment: Are you just using Eclipse or are you writing an eclipse-plugin that will let others display SVG files in eclipse once your plugin is installed?

Answer (score 2):

One possible option is to open a view/editor with the embedded SWT browser. Many browsers now support SVG content, so you could generate inline SVG inside an HTML document and set the browser to display it. See http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet136.java?view=co and others at http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Try this image editor plugin. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/docfacto-toolkit#.UujWxmTFIhg. An image editor "Beermat" is included in the toolkit. Hope it solves your problem.